# Ember app fails in ie9 - blank screen originating from active-model-serializer?

Tags: ember.js, internet-explorer-9, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm having a problem getting my ember app to work in ie9.  I'm using:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.13.3 
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.13.5 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.3 
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I'm getting this error:

`Error while processing route: index, Adapter operation failed`

And a blank screen.  I think i've tracked the issue down to the serializer.  I'm currently using ActiveModelSerializer.  When i remove it, I get more error messages but the errors are consistent across browsers.  Any idea what could be occuring?

Comment: Check your network tab.  What is it returning?  I've seen this fail when trying to send an empty array with success 200.

Comment: i don't actually see it trying to send anything to my api.   it looks like it loads the application's vendor javascript, the application's ember javascript and then fails...  http://i.imgur.com/6f2uCHR.jpg

Comment: I usually get that error when one of my models is missing, does the app work in chrome/safari/ff?

Comment: I've the same issue, did you find where the problem is? My app works in chrome/safari/firefox

Comment: Do you have any warnings/errors in other browsers? Any small error that most browsers gloss over will often break IE. Like a missing semicolon even.